# Confidence on the predictions of DecisionTreeClassifier

Tags: python, scikit-learn, classification, decision-tree, text-classification

I'm trying to understand how classification algorithms work to create a kind of generic pipeline, so I just started with a LinearSVC model. Generally speaking, I'm doing:

```
model = LinearSVC(loss='squared_hinge', penalty='l2', dual=False, tol=1e-3)
model.fit(X_train, y_train)
pred_labels = model.predict(X_unlabeled)  
confidence_on_pred_labels = model.decision_function(X_unlabeled)
```

I really need, as the output, the predicted labels and their confidence. But when I try to do it with other models, I can´t find a way to get the confidences. E.g.

```
model = DecisionTreeClassifier(random_state=0)
model.fit(X_train, y_train)
pred_labels = model.predict(X_unlabeled)  
confidence_on_pred_labels = model.predict_proba(X_unlabeled)
```

In this case, the predict_proba returns, for each predicted label, a tuple containing [0,1] as the values (instead of the confidence between 0 and 1 as a single number). I mean, absolutely all the predictions have a 0.0 or 1.0 value, no values in the middle. E.g. if I run

```
set(model.predict_proba(X_unlabeled)[:,1]) I will get [0.0, 1.0]
```

Is this normal?

How can I get such a number? Or which other models allow me to get the predictions' confidences?
Best,

Answer (score 0):

Is X unlabeled the same data as X without labels? This could be the reason why your probabilities are showing up as [0. 1.]. If you give it data instead that you are trying to actually predict, but is not the same, you should get different probabilities. model.predict_proba should work to show you the class probabilities.

Comment: Hi @Horbaje, thanks for answering. I didn't get the question. X_unlabeled is a csr matrix wich data is, for instance, [62.0465408  36.30498454  4.27042236 ... ]

Comment: And absolutely all the predictions have a o.0 or 1.0 value. Is this normal? E.g. if I run set(model.predict_proba(X_unlabeled)[:,1]) I will get [0.0, 1.0]

Comment: And yes, X_unlabeled  is the data in the target set (withoug labels, to classify)